# Pattern with forward slash (/) is not recognized correctly in Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have some some Strings with `glucose` information's with their corresponding values. For example, a sample String is "FINGER BLOOD GLUCOSE 156 two hours PP" and I have the following program in Java,

```
public class GlucosePattern{


    // test string  
    private static String case1 = "FINGER BLOOD GLUCOSE 156 two hours PP";

    private static  final String decimalValue = "(\\d+(\\.|,)\\d+)|(\\s\\d+(\\s|$))";
    private static final String glucose =  "Glucose.*?";
    private static final Pattern COMPILED_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(glucose+ decimalValue,
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE );


   public Matcher find(final String text) {

       return pattern.matcher(text);
   }

}



// the test of the program 
@Test
public void findWithCase1ShouldFindPattern() throws Exception {

    assertTrue(new GlucosePattern().find(case1).find());
}
```

The provided test returned `true` but, when I used some other String, say, `"Labs showed normal anion gap, glucose 278, u/a w/ 1+ ketones."` the test is failed. I believe this is happened due to the fact of the forward slash "/".

How to improve the Regex to work on properly?

Comment: It is the comma after the 278 that causes the problem. This part of your regex `(\\.|,)\\d+` expects the comma to be followed by at least 1 digit, whereas the other part `(\\s\\d+(\\s|$))` of the regex expects digits to be followed by whitespace.

Comment: Yes, this is solved and I accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your regex is looking for a number and then a space, or a number and then a dot or a comma followed by another number. in the case where it isn't matching it is because there is not a space after the number and there is not a number after the comma.

if you want it to match, you need to update your regex to be like.. `"(\\d+(\\.|,)\\d*)|(\\s\\d+(\\s|$))"`

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with the answers from @user4504267 and @Wernsey, in that the comma after the 278 is causing the second part of the `|` or operator not to match. But you should also double check whether you want `glucose` to be part of the match. As you have it, the regex of `Glucose.*?(\d+(\.|,)\d+)|(\s\d+(\s|$))` matches `glucose 278` in `Labs showed normal anion gap, glucose 278 u/a w/ 1+ ketones.` But it would also match simply 278 in `Labs showed normal anion gap, 278 u/a w/ 1+ ketones.`

This is because the first option before `|` is matching on "glucose  then a group of digits with a single period or comma in it" and the second part is matching "a space followed by a group of digits followed by a space or line end". I suspect you always want to match on glucose first before matching on the number value.

I recommend iterating and testing your regex's on a site like https://regex101.com/ as well as writing java unit tests. You should be able to figure out how to adjust your regex to match and capture exactly what you want with such a site.

Comment: That's true, I would like to match the "glucose" first and if  that't true, I will look for the second part. How can I improve the regex in this context ?
BTW, this is very helpful to point out here.